# jquery mouseover for background parallaxing on mouse position

Tags: jquery, parallax

So here is my code,

```
jQuery(doc­u­ment).ready(func­tion($){
        $(’#Par­al­lax’).mouse­move(
                func­tion(e){
                /* Work out mouse position */
                var off­set = $(this).off­set();
                var xPos = e.pageX - off­set.left;
                var yPos = e.pageY - off­set.top;

                /* Get per­cent­age positions */
                var mou­s­eX­Per­cent = Math.round(xPos / $(this).width() * 100);
                var mou­seY­Per­cent = Math.round(yPos / $(this).height() * 100);

                /* Pos­i­tion Each Layer */
                $(this).chil­dren(‘img’).each(
                        func­tion(){
                                var diffX = $(’#Par­al­lax’).width() - $(this).width();
                                var diffY = $(’#Par­al­lax’).height() - $(this).height();

                                var myX = diffX * (mou­s­eX­Per­cent / 100);
                                var myY = diffY * (mou­seY­Per­cent / 100);
                                var cssObj = {
                                        ‘left’: myX + ‘px’,
                                        ‘top’: myY + ‘px’
                                }
                                $(this).anim­ate({left: myX, top: myY},{dur­a­tion: 50, queue: false, eas­ing: ‘lin­ear’});

                        }
                );

                }
        );
});
```

This works but I need for it to register the mouse position of the entire page and not just when directly hovering over the div #parallax, I'm new to jquery and I do not know what to change it to.

Comment: For some reason changing the binding broke the script and it stopped working, is the '#parallax' pointing to the div, because it needs to locate the images <div id="Parallax"> <img src="images/Top.png" /> <img src="images/Middle.png" /> <img src="images/Bottom.png" /> </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your event handler to `$(document)` instead of `$('#Par­al­lax')`. This way the handler is run whenever the mouse moves anywhere in the document.

Comment: For some reason doing that broke the script and it stopped working, is the '#parallax' pointing to the div, because it needs to locate the images <div id="Parallax">
   <img src="images/Top.png" />
   <img src="images/Middle.png" />
   <img src="images/Bottom.png" />
  </div>